# Java: AlertDialog not printing new line

Tags: java, php, android

My app is using an alert dialog box to display a message obtained from a PHP file.

The message is a couple of strings, and the box should display something like:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

However it is displaying it like:

```
String 1String 2String 3
```

I've tried various ways to add in the new line, both from the php end and on the java end. Here is what I have so far:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
    {
        String message="";
        for(int i =0; i<result.size(); i++)
        {
            message+=result.get(i)+"\n";
        }
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I am obtaining the correct strings from the php file, however the newline is not printing. Is there any other way I can do that? I tried to resize the box but that didn't help at all.

Comment: Did you try adding a System.out.println(); in the for loop?

Comment: in what way would i add that in the for loop? system.out.println the message? but i need it to show in the alertdialog box

Comment: Try `\r` or `\r\n` to make a new line

Comment: none of those worked, but:

i tried doing alertDialog.setMessage("hi"+"\n"+"bye") just to test if that would print a new line, and it did

could the problem be that I'm reading from a php file? and its being transmitted as a html?

Comment: are you sure that you got the right response from the php side?

Comment: no, after   message+=result.get(i)+"\n"; System.out.println();

Answer (score 0):

Use System.lineSeparator(); for newline

```
message += result.get(i) +System.lineSeparator();
```

Comment: this didn't work:/

I'm reading in the string from a php file, does this make a difference?